# Numerical approximations of $2^x$ where $x$ is between $0$ and $1.0$?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponentiation, approximation

I've been looking everywhere for this.  I've found a billion ways to approximate e^x, and ln(x), and I know I could combine those, what I'm looking for here is an *independent* numerical method to calculate $2^x$ with $0.0 < x < 1.0$.  there is one [here](http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/06/fast-approximate-logarithm-exponential.html) but it appears to be using an auto generated polynomial coefficients for numerical approximation, and doesn't really go into detail of how they were chosen.

I figured there would be some series approximation or a analytically derived polynomial expansion, but it seems like that isn't the case (though in that event I'd like to know why, or at least why e^x does and 2^x doesn't).

When I say independent, I mean that the method isn't for say, $e^x$, and then uses some transformation to get to $2^x$. Here's what I don't want, some derivation that comes down to $exp(x * ln(2))$.  Constant log terms like $ln(2)$ are fine, and if it some how helped, an $e^c$ constant would be fine as well. It just can't rely on needing an numerical approximation for $ln(x)$ or $e^x$ or $log_{10}$ etc...

Comment: You can use the fact that $2^x=e^{\ln(2)x}$. The Taylor series is the same as for $\exp$, but basically just with that $\ln(2)$ scaling term. See, for example Wolfram Alpha here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+2%5Ex.

Comment: OP knows how to combine $e^x$ and $\log x$, but wants some method *independent* of those.

Comment: OP could you elaborate on what you mean by independent?

Comment: I second Colin Hicks' question. By definition, $2^x := e^{\log(2)x}$, so...

Comment: @ColinHicks I've clarified.  $e^{log(2)*x}$ is explicitly not allowed, it is not an independent numerical derivation for $2^x$ as it is using another fundamental non constant term.  It relies on a numerical approximation for $e^x$

Answer (score 3):

The Chebyshev series for $2^x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n T_n(2x-1)$
where $$c_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{2^x T_n(2x-1)}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\; dx$$ (except $c_0$ has $1/\pi$ instead of $2/\pi$) where $T_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.  The first few terms are
$$\eqalign{& 1.45699987501296291\,T_0 \left(2\,x-1 \right) + 0.497524867810441862
\,T_1 \left( 2\,x-1 \right) \cr +& 0.0428931119896796484\,T_2 \left( 2\,x-1
 \right) + 0.00247142816399587408\,T_3 \left( 2\,x-1 \right)\cr +&
 0.000106906116358177253\,T_4 \left( 2\,x-1 \right) +
 0.00000370138142770695859\,T_5 \left( 2\,x-1 \right)\cr +&
 0.000000106823753743946597\,T_6 \left( 2\,x-1 \right) +
 0.00000000264303276285357833\,T_7 \left( 2\,x-1 \right)}
$$
which has maximum error less than $6 \times 10^{-11}$.

Comment: I think that you hide $\log(2)$. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not hiding anything.  $\log(2)$ will be involved when you evaluate those integrals in closed form (which I didn't).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici As long as the log term is constant, I don't mind, its when the derivation is actually for $e^x$ and there is some sort of additional modification to make it work for $2^x$

Answer (score 3):

Write $2=\frac{\frac32}{\frac34}=\frac{1+\frac12}{1-\frac14}$ or similarly $2=\frac{1+\frac13}{1-\frac13}$ and apply the binomial series with a sufficiently large number of terms
$$
2^x=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k}2^{-k}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k}(-1)^k4^{-k}}
~~\text{ or }~~
2^x=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k}3^{-k}}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k}(-1)^k3^{-k}}
$$
This of course suffers the fate of all Taylor expansions in that it has very small errors at the development point and large errors at the other end of the interval under consideration. One could reduce that a little by using $2^x=2/2^{1-x}$ for $x$ closer to $1$, or suitably combine both approximations.

Comment: This is really a beautiful approximation. Using summation up to $10$ gives a maximum error equal to $4 \times 10^{-6}$ for the first formula and $2 \times 10^{-7}$ for the second. It looks to be something like the ratio of two gaussian hypergeometric functions. Am I correct ? Cheers.

Comment: for what ever reason I can't see the middle equations, they both get cut off.  Tried firefox though and it works.

Comment: @opa : One can only guess as you did not say what you used when it failed. Is there a problem with formulas in general? What "Math Renderer" is mathjax configured with?

Comment: @LutzL it made them vertical instead of horizontal, but I'm on a different machine with chrome and it works, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @opa : That's strange, but such things happen. Stopping now as it gets off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$2^x=e^{\ln(2)x}$$  you can approximate like before (using taylor series or linear approximation etc). $$1+x\ln(2)+\frac{(x\ln(2))^2}{2}...$$

Comment: OP knows how to combine $e^x$ and $\log x$, but wants some method *independent* of those.

Comment: what does that mean? he could just expand in a taylor series with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f'(0)(x)^n}{n!}$ but he'll just end up getting the exact same thing.

Comment: Indeed, it may not be possible to do what OP wants.

Comment: Then again, some of the answers appear to have succeeded. More than one way to skin an exponential....

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Robert Israel's answer, we have
$$c_n=2 \sqrt{2}\, I_n\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)$$ where $I_n$ is   the modified Bessel function of the first kind and,as Robert Israel wrote
$$2^x= \sqrt{2}I_0\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)+2 \sqrt{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)\, T_n(2x-1)$$

Computing the maximum error $\Delta$ for the partial sum up to $p$, a quick and dirty linear regression gives $(R^2=0.9986)$
$$\log_{10}(|\Delta|)=0.90352 -1.60856 \,p$$

If you accept $\color{blue}{a=\log(2)}$ to be part of the approximation and assuming that you are noot too much requiring about accuracy, you could use an $[n,n]$ Padé approximant built at $x=\frac 12$ and get, for example,
$$\color{blue}{2 ^x \sim \sqrt 2\,\frac {1+\frac{a }{2}t+\frac{a^2 }{10}t^2+\frac{a^3 }{120}t^3 } {1-\frac{a }{2}t+\frac{a^2 }{10}t^2-\frac{a^3 }{120}t^3 }}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{t=x-\frac 12}$$ which leads to a maximum error equal to $1.2 \times 10^{-8}$.

**Edit**

If we use the $[n,n]$ Padé approximant built at $x=\frac 12$,we have $(R^2=0.9981)$
$$\log_{10}(|\Delta|)=1.23774 -3.13141  \,n$$ For $n=5$, it would be
$$\color{blue}{2^x\sim \sqrt 2\,\frac{30240+15120 y+3360 y^2+420 y^3+30 y^4+y^5} {30240-15120 y+3360 y^2-420 y^3+30 y^4-y^5 }}$$
 where $\color{blue}{y=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)}$ and the maximum error is $2.44\times 10^{-15}$.

In fact, the general $[n,n]$ Padé approximant built at $x=\frac 12$ can write as
$$\color{red}{2^x \sim \sqrt 2\,\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(k+n)! }{k! (n-k)!}y^{n-k}} { \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{(k+n)! }{k! (n-k)!}y^{n-k}}}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{red}{y=\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)}$$

Comment: interesting, is that relative error or absolute error?

Comment: @opa. It the the maximum of the  absolute error. But, if Padé approximant is of some interest to you, I can generate better and using $at$ as variable plus Horner scheme for top and bottom, it could be quite inexpensive in terms of computer resources. Let me know.